# click tap or touch begin and drag an object on the same time as3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, swipe, tap

i am creating a buttons bar that can be dragged however when i lift my finger after dragging the buttons the button is getting pushed, i would like to cancel the click/tap when dragging the buttons any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to remove/add your listeners as necessary, or have a property on your buttons. Something like:

```
public class DragButton extends Sprite
{
    public var isDragging:Boolean = false;

    public function DragButton()
    {
        // add our listeners
        this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this._onMouseDown );
        this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this._onMouseUp );
        this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this._onMouseClick );
    }

    private function _onMouseDown( e:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        // add our move listener for dragging
        this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this._onMouseMove );
    }

    private function _onMouseUp( e:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        // remove our dragging listener
        this.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this._onMouseMove );
    }

    private function _onMouseMove( e:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        // drag us
        this.x = e.stageX;
        this.y = e.stageY;
        this.isDragging = true;
    }

    private function _onMouseClick( e:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        // if we're dragging, ignore
        if( this.isDragging )
        {
            this.isDragging = false;
            return;
        }

        // do our click stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: mmmm, i though about this, i was sure there is something better to do

Comment: In AS3, the order of events is always `MOUSE_DOWN`, `MOUSE_UP`, then `CLICK`. If you don't want the `CLICK` after you mouse up from dragging it, then you either need to remove the click listener and re-add it later, or implement something like the above to ignore it. You could also try setting `mouseEnabled` to `false` in the `MOUSE_UP` event, but again, you'll need to reset it later